# Check if one of strings in once column found in the other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Im trying to check if one of strings in column `Name B` is found in column `Name A` by creating new column `Name Check`:

Current Inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name A":{"0":"John","1":"Sara","2":"Adam","3":"Ahmed"},
                   "Name B":{"0":"John, Geroge","1":"Ahemed, Sara","2":"Adam, Nadia","3":"Sara, John"},
                   "Salary":{"0":100,"1":200,"2":300,"3":400}})

    Name A  Name B        Salary
0   John    John, Geroge  100
1   Sara    Ahemed, Sara  200
2   Adam    Adam, Nadia   300
3   Ahmed   Sara, John    400
```

Excepted Output :

```
    Name A  Name B        Salary  Name Check
0   John    John, Geroge  100     True
1   Sara    Ahemed, Sara  200     True
2   Adam    Adam, Nadia   300     True
3   Ahmed   Sara, John    400     False
4   Nadi    Sara, Nadia   500     True
5   George  Georg, Mo     600     True
```

What i have tried :

```
df['Name Check'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Name B'] in x['Name A'] , axis=1)
```

But the output is all **False**, not sure how to convert column `Name B` to a list and loop through to check one by one if found in column `Name A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible split by `,` with optionaly space use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df['Name Check'] = (df['Name B'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True)
                                .isin(df['Name A']).any(axis=1))
```

For test splitted substrings use:

```
f = lambda x: any(y in x['Name A'] or x['Name A'] in y for y in x['Name B'].split(', '))
df['Name Check1'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Note for the second approach, this will match on the whole string (i.e., 'Anna' would match 'Annalisa')

Comment: That worked perfectly!, but how can i match on substring ?

Comment: @IbraheemAyoup - Do you think `df['Name Check'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Name A'] in x['Name B'] , axis=1)` ?

Comment: Tried this but didnot work, now sure how to loop through the strings in column Name B

Comment: then you should explain what you mean by *partial matching* (give examples)

Comment: @IbraheemAyoup - `how to loop through the strings` - do you think splittev values by `,  ` ?

Comment: @jezrael Just added examples in row 4 & 5, refer to expected output table, what is required is to match column Name B with column Name A based on substring.

Comment: @IbraheemAyoup - Can you test now edited answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a regex with word boundaries:

```
import re
df.apply(lambda r: bool(re.search(r'\b%s\b' % r['Name A'], r['Name B'])), axis=1)
```

Explanation: this defines a regex per row of the form `\bJohn\b`, which ensures a full match is done

Comment: Just added two examples (in row 4 & 5 "Expcted output") to match on substrings.